# Eclipse - How to sort package explorer non alphabetically?

Tags: eclipse, syntax

Using eclipse; this is what my package explorer looks like:

[image]

I want org.plx to be above com.rs

How can I do this?

I have seen some threads on here with this but nobody has said where and in which menu we can modify whether the explorer is sorted alphabetically or not.

Comment: What guides show this? Package Explorer doesn't support this.

Comment: There are thread in here of people saying its possible but no guides on how to actually do it

Comment: Which Eclipse version?

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse Oxygen (at least) it's possible to workaround that by writing your own package abbreviation rules on

> Preferences > Java > Appearance > [x] Abbreviate package names

There, write rules like

> org.plx=[A.plx]
>   com.rs=[B.rs]

or

> org.plx=1.plx
>   com.rs=2.rs

Comment: This is a nice way to shorten the package name, but unfortunately the package/project explorer does not use the abbreviated name when sorting the packages. So you cannot use this trick to reorder the packages.

Comment: Create a bug for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558784